# Calculating a cumulative deficit index

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I have a dataset of blood analytes that look like this:

| alb | alp | na | pot | alb_zscore | alp_zscore | na_zscore | pot_zscore |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5.37 | 86. | 142 | 6.73 | -7.82 | -0.95 | 0 | 3.1 |
| 4.67 | 28 | 127 | 23.87 | -0.35 | 2.31 | 1.39 | 6.3 |
| 4.43 | 170 | NA | 4.27 | -2.29 | -0.14 | NA | -1.4 |
| 3.75 | 12 | 164 | 3.05 | -2.88 | 5.86 | 0.26 | -3.5 |
| 4.85 | NA | 139 | 6.75 | -4.72 | NA | 8.23 | -3.64 |

I have many more analytes/columns but I chose this for simplicity sake. There are ~1500 rows, where each row is an individual. Please note the numbers in the example table are random/made-up (in case you are wondering why the corresponding z-scores seem so wonky).

For context, I'm creating an index of dysregulation for each individual. For some analytes, a value that is too high can represent dysregulation; for other analytes, a low value represents dysregulation; and for other analytes, either a high or low value represents dysregulation. The number of analytes that are in dysregulation per individual are then summed, to create something called a Cumulative Deficit Index (see Noppert et al. 2018 if curious to learn more).

For my code, I aim to split each analyte_zscore into quartiles (although analytes could be split into octiles instead- see more below) and those in the highest (or lowest) quartile of the distribution receive a score of 1. Ultimately, I want a column called 'dysreg_index' that is the sum of the number of analytes for which an individual received a score of 1, divided by the total number of analytes available for that individual. Some individuals have NAs for an analyte value - I do not want any analyte with an NA counted towards the total number of analytes for that individual.

Given that I have many analytes each with their own 'rule' of what constitutes dysregulation, I would like the code to be customizable. For the purpose of this example, pretend that these are the rules of what constitutes dysregulation...

```
alb_zscore: lower quartile (<25%),
alp_zscore: upper quartle (>75%),
na_zscore: lower or upper quartile (<25% or >75%),
pot_zscore: lower or upper octile (<12.5% or >87.5%)
```

(Note: this isn't code, but Stack thought it was and wouldn't let me post it without formatting it as such)

Any help in creating this code would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

*Source: Noppert GA, Aiello AE, O’Rand AM, Cohen HJ (2018). Investigating pathogen burden in relation to a cumulative deficits index in a representative sample of US adults. Epidemiology and Infection 146, 1968–1976. https://doi.org/10.1017/S095026881800153X*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to have a "dictionary" of functions to evaluate 0/1 for a particular column.

```r
funcs <- list(
  alb_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & z < quantile(z, 0.25, na.rm = TRUE),
  alp_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & z > quantile(z, 0.75, na.rm = TRUE),
  na_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & !between(z, quantile(z, 0.25, na.rm = TRUE), quantile(z, 0.75, na.rm = TRUE)),
  pot_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & !between(z, quantile(z, 0.125, na.rm = TRUE), quantile(z, 0.875, na.rm = TRUE))
)
```

With that, we can do:

```r
mapply(function(fn, x) fn(x), funcs, quux[names(funcs)])
#      alb_zscore alp_zscore na_zscore pot_zscore
# [1,]       TRUE      FALSE      TRUE      FALSE
# [2,]      FALSE      FALSE     FALSE       TRUE
# [3,]      FALSE      FALSE     FALSE      FALSE
# [4,]      FALSE       TRUE     FALSE      FALSE
# [5,]      FALSE      FALSE      TRUE       TRUE
```

With this, we can easily use `rowSums` to come up with your `dysreg_index`. *Edited* to divide by the number of non-`NA` elements in the row:

```r
quux %>%
  mutate(
    dysreg_index = {
      num <- mapply(function(fn, x) fn(x), funcs, pick(all_of(names(funcs))))
      den <- (!is.na(pick(all_of(names(funcs)))))
      rowSums(num) / rowSums(den)
    }
  )
#    alb alp  na   pot alb_zscore alp_zscore na_zscore pot_zscore dysreg_index
# 1 5.37  86 142  6.73      -7.82      -0.95      0.00       3.10    0.5000000
# 2 4.67  28 127 23.87      -0.35       2.31      1.39       6.30    0.2500000
# 3 4.43 170  NA  4.27      -2.29      -0.14        NA      -1.40    0.0000000
# 4 3.75  12 164  3.05      -2.88       5.86      0.26      -3.50    0.2500000
# 5 4.85  NA 139  6.75      -4.72         NA      8.23      -3.64    0.6666667
```

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(alb = c(5.37, 4.67, 4.43, 3.75, 4.85), alp = c(86, 28, 170, 12, NA), na = c(142L, 127L, NA, 164L, 139L), pot = c(6.73, 23.87, 4.27, 3.05, 6.75), alb_zscore = c(-7.82, -0.35, -2.29, -2.88, -4.72), alp_zscore = c(-0.95, 2.31, -0.14, 5.86, NA), na_zscore = c(0, 1.39, NA, 0.26, 8.23), pot_zscore = c(3.1, 6.3, -1.4, -3.5, -3.64)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thank you SO much! For the dysreg_index, I was hoping it would be in the form of a fraction - eg, # analytes in dysregulation / total # of analytes available for that individual (excluding NAs). Are you able to modify the code to perform that? Thank you again for your time!

Comment: Thank you! Just to check, does this code account for removing the NAs? IE, for row 5, since alp is NA, I would not want that counted towards the denominator for row 5's dysreg_score. Instead I would like the dysreg_score for row 5 to be like, 2 TRUES / 3 analytes = 0.67.

Comment: the `na.rm=TRUE` means that `NA`s are not considered when calculating the quantiles, so while it does not count against the premise of "below 25%" (e.g.), it is still counting when considering fractions

Comment: Thank you. I guess I am still confused: If that is the case, then why isn't row 5's dysreg_score 0.67?

Comment: That's my point: when determining the quantiles to determine if a row(s) is an outlier of the column, the number of observations (columns) in each row is unchanging at 5. If you need it to be 0.67, we can do that too

Comment: If we could do that too, that would be great - thank you so much!

Comment: @ r2evans. I thought SO wasn’t supposed to be a code server?

Comment: @burphound, for the denominator, use rowsums similar to the numerator, only testing for is.na instead of outside a particular quantile

Comment: I figured out the solution - it's not elegant but I'm happy! For the denominator I did 
 (ncol(z) - rowSums(is.na(cbind(quux$alb_zscore, quux$alp_zscore, quux$na_zscore, quux$pot_zscore))))

Comment: @r2evans, so sorry to bother you again. Something I forgot to put in my OG question is that I want to perform the quantile function on grouped data. I tried doing quux %>% group_by(sex) %>% mutate(#all the syntax) %>% ungroup()   but I get this error: Error in `mutate()`: In argument: `dysreg_index = { ... }`.
In group 1: `sex = 1`. Caused by error:
! `dysreg_index` must be size 518 or 1, not 921.

Any advice on how to perform the quantile function, grouped by sex?

Comment: @burphound, I edited the question to include the mention of `rowSums` and `is.na` that I made earlier, you can a cue from the use the `pick(..)` methodology I demonstrated in the first (numerator) condition in order to calculate the denominators. As for an error, since you're using `group_by`, you must never reference `quux` within a `mutate`, that is why we use things like `pick(.)` so that we see the data as it stands at that point in the data pipe (including with grouping). I suggest you read more about https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/grouping.html and `pick`.

Comment: @r2evans, thank you so much. Say I now only wanted alb_zscore and alp_zscore to be a part of dysreg_index. I tried doing:
num <- mapply(..., pick(names(funcs[c(1,2)])))
den <- (!is.na(pick(names(funcs[c(1,2)]))))
But I don't think this is right. I know the dysreg_index should be (in order, rows 1-5) 0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.  But instead, I get 1.5, 0.5, 0, 1, 0.  Do you have any advice on picking only certain elements of funcs?

Comment: (1) Better option is to define `funcs` based on exactly what you want. (2) However, my bet is that you did not fix the solitary `funcs` in the second argument of `mapply`. Make sure it's something like `num <- mapply(function(fn, x) fn(x), funcs[1:2], pick(all_of(names(funcs[1:2]))))`. (3) ***Learn to use `browser()`.*** If you do `mutate(disreg_index = { browser(); ...}` and step through each expression, you would see that `num` has 4 columns while `den` has 2, immediately identifying a problem.

Comment: You are correct on #2, thank you for catching that. And thank you for introducing me to browser() !